# android java Httpclient connection

Tags: java, android

Ok, so my `HttpClient` call is not working in java android i tried to surround it with try and catch and it keeps on failing. Please Help!!!

```
     BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI ur = new URI("http://192.168.1.10/test/randomy/generate/index.php");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(ur);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String l = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("test");
        while((l=in.readLine())!=null){

            sb.append(l);

        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if(in!=null){

            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return "Error";
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Have you added internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: yeah i did. but how do you read the errors?

Comment: Is that link working in browser. Did you try to get response when you hit that link in browser>

Comment: @Sam Check your logcat does it give you any errors?

Comment: write this inside your `catch ` Log.e("error in parse", ""+e); and post the error here

Comment: ok it says error in parse android.os.networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: @Sam use my code and read the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network operations should be done on separate tread. you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)  or surround with

```
new Thread (){

public void run() {
 //your code
}
};
```

and you can also disable the error by using

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

on oncreate method.

Answer (score 1):

use this && read this [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
class testAsynk extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        Log.d("PreExceute","On pre Exceute......");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
        Log.d("DoINBackGround","On doInBackground...");
//Send the Http Request
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Integer in = new Integer(i);
            publishProgress(i);
        }
        return "You are at PostExecute";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...a){
        Log.d("You are in progress update ... " + a[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d(""+result);
    }
}
```

**Calling From the Activity **

```
new testAsynk().execute();
```